# Create Azure Function without Application Insights using PowerShell

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Function without having an Application Insights instance created/connected. Assumed this would do the trick, using 'DisableApplicationInsights':

```
New-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -Runtime $Runtime -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -PlanName $AppServicePlanName -RuntimeVersion $RuntimeVersion -DisableApplicationInsights
```

It does however create an Application Insights instance, but not connect it to the Function. I was expecting no Application Insights instance created. Not sure why it's created and not connected to the Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12728) at this moment which is in backlog for next major release. Until then, you need to delete the created application insights resource after Function creation.

```
Remove-AzApplicationInsights $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName
```